# Business Intelligence - Parameters in Stored Procedure vs. BI Tool

Tags: stored-procedures, business-intelligence

Summary: What are the pros and cons of including a user's parameters in a stored procedure vs the BI dashboard.

I am new to BI and have been tasked with using a Stored Procedure as the data source for a dashboard.  I am wondering what the performance differences are if I include report parameters in the stored procedure vs including them in the dashboard.

For example:

A user wishes to compare data from two dates, therefore there are a `FirstDate` and `LastDate` parameter. I could include the parameters in the stored procedure and have the user specify the dates before any data loads. On the contrary, I could import all data returned from the stored procedure (without parameters) and then prompt the user for dates.

The reason I ask is due to scenarios where the user would want to change the date parameters. When the parameters change the data must be refreshed and I am wondering how to optimize the whole interaction between the dashboard and user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of putting your parameters on the stored procedure (or the query) it's that the database will return data quickier and your application will use less memory, but as in everything, there is a trade off, as if you want to select different parameters, you need to return to the database which may be slow.

In the end, you must weight if it's more important to use less resources or be quickier, and optimize accordingly.